The name of the complex factor $e^{j\omega t}$
In Fourier analysis, time-harmonic functions are modeled by using the complex factor $e^{j\omega t}$, where $t$ is time and $\omega$ is the angular frequency and $j=\sqrt{-1}$ is the imaginary unit.
Is there any conventional/standard name for the factor $e^{j\omega t}$?

I usually call this a pure frequency, but not sure how 'established' that is.
